# When do I get "overloaded definition needed" error?

Tags: c++, overloading

Take this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Display(char a, char b, char c)
{
   cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
}

int main()
{
   Display(2, 3, 4); // Why no syntax error?
   Display(2.0, 3.0, 4.0); // Also no error? O.o
   Display('a', 'b', 'c');
 
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

I was expecting errors on the first two Display() calls, that would say:

> No definition for Display() that takes (int, int, int) found.
>
> No definition for Display() that takes (double, double, double) found.

Where then I would have to overload Display() and add ones that accept the proper parameters.

So in what cases do I actually get the syntax error? And why I did not get the error in this case?

Comment: Conversion from an `int` to a `char` is part of the standard conversions. More at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The OP says they expect to get an error, not that they did.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ha? There is NO error, which is why I am asking here ...

Comment: @Nathan OMG, I just realised that. Stupid me :-(

Comment: That should give truncation warnings but not errors. If you want to force an error, you should look at `explicit`.

Comment: @SandraK At least your question title seems to have misled me.

Comment: @Tzalumen Why?  What is being truncated?

Comment: @Tzalumen I don't see the truncation. And where would you put `explicit`? I've only ever seen it used on constructors and conversion operators.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That... might actually be C++20 that has it. disappointing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think I am incorrect in assuming they made the specifier available for all functions. Maybe they will in the next revision :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how C++ works.  The compiler will try to implicitly convert the type you give it to the type it needs, even if it is a narrowing conversion (an exception was made if doing brace initialization.  There you get an error).  In this case it will convert the `int` that you give it into a `char` with the same value an continue on.

Since all of the values you provided are compile time constants in the range of [0, 127], this can never fail so you won't even get a warning that you could be overflowing.

If you had used something like

```
Display(2000, 32, 47);
```

You would get warning from GCC and Clang like

```
GCC
main.cpp:12:12: warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from '2000' to ''\37777777720'' [-Woverflow]
    Display(2000, 32, 47);

Clang   
main.cpp:12:12: warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 2000 to -48 [-Wconstant-conversion]
    Display(2000, 32, 47);
```

Letting you know you're doing something bad, but it can only do so if it knows what the values are.  If you have

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    Display(a, b, c);
    Display('a', 'b', 'c');

    return 0;
}
```

Then it doesn't know what the values are so it won't issue a warning.

If you really want to stop this you can add an overload that takes `int`s and delete it so it will cause a compiler error like

```
void Display(char a, char b, char c)
{
   cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
}

void Display(int, int, int) = delete;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    Display(a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:31:20: error: use of deleted function 'void Display(int, int, int)'
     Display(a, b, c);
                    ^
prog.cc:25:6: note: declared here
 void Display(int, int, int) = delete;
```

You can also go all out and use

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
void Display(T, U, V) = delete;
```

and this will make calling `Display` an error with anything other than 3 `char`s.

Comment: Note to future askers: Heed the bit about the compiler warnings. Don't ignore them. Sure, the program compiles and runs, but the warning is the compiler telling you it might not run quite the way you expect. Taking advantage of warnings can save you a lot of debugging.

Answer (score 4):

An `int` can be converted to a `char` because of [Standard conversions/Integral convesions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.integral#1).

> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.

The definition of *integer type* can be seen at [Basic concepts/Fundamental types](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.fundamental#7).

> Types `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called *integral* types. A synonym for integral type is *integer type*.

---

A `double` can also be conerted to a `char` due to [Standard conversions/Floating-integral conversions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.fpint).

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Because the values are implicitly converted. This is also called automatic type conversion. Chars are an integer type, so they are threaded like any other int - assigning a double or a float to an int will truncate the value.

This is pretty common, virtually all programming languages I can think of do this.

Comment: @SandraK _"But in what cases I actually get the error?"_ In cases you don't have implicit conversions. Try e.g. with two different enum types, or some complex type like `std::string`.